# Getting error MSB4803: The task "ResolveCo mReference" is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, specflow

I have created an Automation framework based on Xunit and Specflow having .netcore 3.1. This Automation Framework uses com reference to automate an application. I am able to run it through Visual Studio 2019 IDE but unable to run the Test cases using "dotnet test" or mstest command line commands. For dotnet test command it throws this error

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2927,5): error MSB4803: The task "ResolveComReference" is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild. Please use the .NET Framework version of MSBuild. See
> https://aka.ms/msbuild/MSB4803 for further details."

I am unable to find suitable solution for this till now. Please help me to understand the root cause.

I have to run the Automation Scripts through Jenkin jobs but unable to find suitable commands to run it through command line. I tried running from command line from my machine but none of the command line worked yet.

Comment: The MS page gives you a suggestion : use MSBuild instead of dotnet build command. I guess it's supported by jenkins. Did you tried that ?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include more information? I'm honestly not sure what information would make this an answerable question. We need to know the software and SDK's installed on the machine, which version of Jenkins you have, which plugins are installed (and the plugin versions), and additional information about the Jenkins build itself.

Comment: You cannot use `dotnet test` for this, apparently. You will likely need to update from .NET Core 3.x to .NET 5, 6, or 7.